# Asterisk server in Debian linux

Tags: ssh, asterisk

I m tried to download sip.conf files in asterisk server with ssh it replies sip.conf is not a regular file,directory or symlink?

Answer (score 0):

If you have elastic it is symlink to /var/www/html/admin/core/etc/sip.conf

Answer (score 0):

From which location you tried to download the file. In a normal installation this file will be in "/etc/asterisk"